# Selecting coefficients of a complicated differential equation

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

I have a nonlinear differential equation having a parameter *u* and the following terms: *{w, w', w'', phi, phi', phi'', beta, beta', beta'', rw, rw', rw'', rp, rp', rp'', rb, rb', rb'',phi^2}*. I would like to obtain an array having the coefficients of these terms as functions of the parameter *u*, and an extra term containing the remaning.
This is the differential equation:

```
    1.00933*10^8 w[t] - 
 0.397654 u^2 Sin[366.095/
   u^2] (2.05863*10^7/u^4 + (659791. phi[t])/u^2 + 5679.79 phi[t]^2 + 
    2. (-(2.08696*10^7/u^4) - (169470. Cot[366.095/u^2])/u^2 - (
       1.23229*10^8 Csc[366.095/u^2])/u^4 + (1/(u^6))
       7.01408*10^-39 Csc[366.095/
         u^2] \[Sqrt]((1.75688*10^46 u^2 + 
             2.41614*10^43 u^4 Cos[366.095/u^2] + 
             2.97539*10^45 u^2 Sin[366.095/u^2])^2 - 
           9.40666*10^43 u^4 Sin[366.095/
             u^2] (2.03638*10^45 u^2 + 
              9.16129*10^44 u^2 Cos[366.095/u^2] + 
              1.02791*10^47 Sin[366.095/u^2] + 
              1.17984*10^40 u^4 Sin[366.095/u^2]))) + 
    2. phi[t] (-(359311./u^2) - 2917.75 Cot[366.095/u^2] - (
       2.12162*10^6 Csc[366.095/u^2])/u^2 + (1/(u^4))
       1.20761*10^-40 Csc[366.095/
         u^2] \[Sqrt]((1.75688*10^46 u^2 + 
             2.41614*10^43 u^4 Cos[366.095/u^2] + 
             2.97539*10^45 u^2 Sin[366.095/u^2])^2 - 
           9.40666*10^43 u^4 Sin[366.095/
             u^2] (2.03638*10^45 u^2 + 
              9.16129*10^44 u^2 Cos[366.095/u^2] + 
              1.02791*10^47 Sin[366.095/u^2] + 
              1.17984*10^40 u^4 Sin[366.095/u^2]))) + (1/(u^8))
    2.56756*10^-84 (-2.97539*10^45 u^2 - 
       2.41614*10^43 u^4 Cot[366.095/u^2] - 
       1.75688*10^46 u^2 Csc[366.095/u^2] + 
       Csc[366.095/
         u^2] \[Sqrt](u^4 ((1.75688*10^46 + 
               2.41614*10^43 u^2 Cos[366.095/u^2] + 
               2.97539*10^45 Sin[366.095/u^2])^2 - 
             9.40666*10^43 Sin[366.095/
               u^2] (2.03638*10^45 u^2 + 
                9.16129*10^44 u^2 Cos[366.095/
                  u^2] + (1.02791*10^47 + 1.17984*10^40 u^4) Sin[
                  366.095/u^2]))))^2 + (
    437861. Derivative[1][phi][t])/u^3 + 
    1.5 (-(312719./u^3) - (2539.41 Cot[366.095/u^2])/u - (
       1.84651*10^6 Csc[366.095/u^2])/u^3 + (1/(u^5))
       1.05102*10^-40 Csc[366.095/
         u^2] \[Sqrt](u^4 ((1.75688*10^46 + 
               2.41614*10^43 u^2 Cos[366.095/u^2] + 
               2.97539*10^45 Sin[366.095/u^2])^2 - 
             9.40666*10^43 Sin[366.095/
               u^2] (2.03638*10^45 u^2 + 
                9.16129*10^44 u^2 Cos[366.095/
                  u^2] + (1.02791*10^47 + 1.17984*10^40 u^4) Sin[
                  366.095/u^2])))) Derivative[1][phi][t]) + 
 1021.49 (beta^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] - 
 81644.8 (phi^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
 1.52994*10^6 (w^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] - 
 1. Cos[366.095/
   u^2] (2.59496 u (4.39439 u^2 rb[t] + 79.1949 u^2 rp[t] + 
       499.168 u^2 rw[t] + 46.33 u Derivative[1][rb][t] + 
       804.864 u Derivative[1][rp][t] + 
       5151.13 u Derivative[1][rw][t] + 
       50.0016 (rb^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
       901.12 (rp^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
       5679.79 (rw^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]) + 
    1.29748 (3.58313 u Derivative[1][beta][t] + 
       797.355 u Derivative[1][phi][t] + 
       0.34362 (beta^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
       354.831 (phi^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] + 
       4943.29 (w^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]))
```

Any suggestions? My final goal would be to write a set of differential equations in matrix form.

**UPDATE**

I have taken the coefficients in a row form, but still can't find a way to get the remaining terms.

```
coefficients = -CoefficientArrays[equation==0, {w[t], w'[t], w''[t], phi[t], 
 phi'[t], phi''[t], beta[t], beta'[t], beta''[t], rw[t], rw'[t], 
 rw''[t], rp[t], rp'[t], rp''[t], rb[t], rb'[t], rb''[t], 
 phi[t]^2,}][[2]]
```

Comment: Have a look at `Select` and `FreeQ`. See here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SelectingPartsOfExpressionsWithFunctions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the solution was right under my nose (after my last update).

This would return the coefficients of the terms:

```
 coefficients = -CoefficientArrays[equation==0, {w[t], w'[t], w''[t], phi[t], 
 phi'[t], phi''[t], beta[t], beta'[t], beta''[t], rw[t], rw'[t], 
 rw''[t], rp[t], rp'[t], rp''[t], rb[t], rb'[t], rb''[t], 
 phi[t]^2,}][[2]]
```

As for the remaining terms, it is only about changing one character:

```
coefficients = -CoefficientArrays[equation==0, {w[t], w'[t], w''[t], phi[t], 
     phi'[t], phi''[t], beta[t], beta'[t], beta''[t], rw[t], rw'[t], 
     rw''[t], rp[t], rp'[t], rp''[t], rb[t], rb'[t], rb''[t], 
     phi[t]^2,}][[1]]
```